# Don't show points in ggbiplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggbiplot

Using ggbiplot, how can I hide the points from the plot so that only the vectors are shown? I know I can modify the points by adding `geom_point()` but as it does not seem to be possible to plot `geom_point()` behind the `ggbiplot()` layer e.g. setting the background colour as the point colour does not work.

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale = TRUE)
ggbiplot::ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1)
```

Comment: Just set `alpha = 0`.

Comment: Aahh, I tried everything in `geom_point`, but didn't consider that I have to set this in the` ggbiplot` layer directly, thanks!